# Between statement include both conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, between

I have a query that looks like this

```
     SELECT * from myTable WHERE Date BETWEEN @Sunday AND @Saturday
```

I want this query to include elements that occured on sunday and on saturday too. I know I could just change the values to `Between @Saturday AND @Sunday` but let's say I don't want to change the date calculation algorithm is there a way to include both dates ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use `BETWEEN` for date/time range queries. If you want anything that happened from Sunday at midnight to Saturday at 23:59:59.9999999, the safest way using any date/time data type is:

```
DECLARE @Sunday DATE = '20120617';

...
WHERE [Date] >= @Sunday AND [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, 7, @Sunday);
```

Please give these two articles a read:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: Looks like I found THE good person too answer my question :P Nice article by the way very clear. I think  ill read a few more of your articles before I go on with my project.